# Why second spin in Spinlock gives performance boost?

Tags: c++, performance, atomic

Here is a basic Spinlock implemented with `std::atomic_flag`.
The author of the [book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/High-Performance-Master-optimizing-functioning/dp/1839216549/ref=asc_df_1839216549/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=463212453779&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=1927972383387229325&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9044966&hvtargid=pla-1045131212877&psc=1&th=1&psc=1) claims that second while in the `lock()` boosts performance.

```
class Spinlock
{
    std::atomic_flag flag{};
public:
    void lock() {
        while (flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
            while (flag.test(std::memory_order_acquire)); //Spin here
        }
    }
    void unlock() {
        flag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    }
};
```

> The reason we use `test()` in an extra inner loop is performance:
> `test()` doesn't invalidate cache line, whereas `test_and_set()` does.

Can someone please elaborate on this quote? Test is still a read operation and need to be read from memory right?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Reading a memory address does not clear the cache line.

Writing does.

So in a modern computer, there is RAM, and there are multiple layers of cache "around" the CPU (they are called L1, L2 and L3 cache, but the important part is that they are layers, and the CPU is at the middle).  In a multi-core system, often the outer layers are shared; the innermost layer is usually not, and is specific to a given CPU.

Clearing the cache line means informing every other cache holding this memory "the data you own may be stale, throw it out".

Test and set writes true and atomically returns the old value.  It clears the cache line, because it writes.

Test does not write.  If you have another thread unsynchronized  with this one, it reading the cache of this memory doesn't have to be poked.

The outer loop writes true, and exits if it replaced false.  The inner loop waits until there is a false visible, then falls to outer loop.  The inner loop need not clear every other cpu's cache status of the value of the atomic flag, but the outer has to (as it could change the false to true).  As spinning could go on for a while, avoiding continuous cache clearing seems like a good idea.

Comment: I think the poster is more confused about CPU memory caching (i.e. a read may not actually access RAM)

Comment: @CollinDauphinee Added a paragraph about CPU memory caching.

Comment: Need to explain the low level combined testAndSet machine instruction and what it does to the cache line if it does not do the set.

Answer (score 3):

An (atomic) store need exclusive access to a cache line, but a plain atomic (release) store is still relatively efficient because store buffer 'caching' is involved; ie. immediate access to the cache line is not required.

In the spinlock example, the store (`test_and_set`) is an atomic read-modify-write (RMW) operation, which is significantly slower due to its nature; it both reads and writes in a single operation.
That requires instant access to the cache line while anything still pending in the store buffer must be flushed before it can proceed.
In addition, the cache line must be locked to ensure exclusive access between the read and write.
This is expensive, but it's required for the spinlock to guarantee exclusive lock access.

When multiple threads are stomping on the same `test_and_set` operation, the cache line keeps bouncing between CPU cores.
The inner loop (with the atomic read) is an optimization because multiple threads/cores can have read-only access to the same cache line ('SHARED' in the MESI cache coherency protocol).
Once the inner-loop `test` operation reads `false`, the `test_and_set` in the outer-loop acquires the lock and only at that point, `std::memory_order_acquire` is needed.
Using 'acquire' on the `test` operation in the inner loop is therefore pointless and a pessimization on weaker architectures where `memory_order_acquire` entails an extra CPU instruction (eg. PowerPC).
Since the inner loop is all about optimization, it should use `std::memory_order_relaxed`.

```
    void lock() {
        while (flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
            while (flag.test(std::memory_order_relaxed)); //Spin here
        }
    }
```

To optimize further, a standalone fence could be used so that the CPU fencing instruction is *only* called after a thread has acquired the lock flag.

```
class Spinlock
{
    std::atomic_flag flag{};
public:
    void lock() {
        while (flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
            while (flag.test(std::memory_order_relaxed)); //Spin here
        }
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    }
    void unlock() {
        flag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    }
};
```

Is having an inner loop a useful optimization? - perhaps.. it won't hurt, but if the inner loop is frequently reached, there is some contention and a spin lock is probably not the right tool.